# Что лучше использовать: сессии или куки?

Tags: php, cookie, сессия

У меня на сайте все блоки обновляются через jQuery. Так как хочу сократить SQL запросы, хочу сделать маленький кэш. И вот думаю использовать сессии.

Суть вопроса: что лучше использовать сессию или куки? Для каждого блока - разное время обновления.

Comment: Если вопрос не ясне, могу перефразировать

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если вам надо хранить интерфейсную информацию: например, чтобы отмеченные чекбоксы не сбрасывались при перезагрузке страницы, то используйте куки. Если вы хотите хранить информацию, связанную с безопасностью, то однозначно сессии - их подменить можно, но очень трудно.
И да, как уже было сказано, и то, и то не работает при выключенных куках.

Answer (score 0):

Советую помнить, что куки хранят не более 4кб инфы. В сессии тоже не запихать много. Так что решайте сами, что юзать.

Comment: А что быстрее? И лучше использовать? Файловый кэшь быстрее, чем куки?

Comment: В любом случае, если сайт будет юзать сессию, то файл ее будет грузиться так, что сказать по скорости точно нельзя. При загруженности 10000 сессий и слабом сервере само собой у вас   будет доступ к сессии медленнее, чем к кукам, переданным в запросе. Но помнить надо, что и их прием при слабом сервере будет тоже не особо быстрый. Панацеи нет. Можете юзать и то, и то. Учитывайте время хранения. Не думаю, что доля секунды решит вопрос для вас.

Answer (score 0):

Куки хранятся у клиента, а сессии занимают некоторое место на сервере. Я бы советовал выбрать куки, если хранить надо 2-3 записи.

Comment: С каждым запросом через аякс куки будут передаваться на сервер. Так что можно просчитать так - что лучше? Передача всего вороха куков или подгрузка файла сессии. Я обычно за сессию в таких случаях, ибо куки можно подменить, а данные сессии нет. Но в любом случае всегда выбор за прогером.
давайте оценим плюсы и минусы: куки-- плюсы - настройка времени хранения.
минусы: возможность изменения пользователем.
постоянная передача на сервер в запросе (возможность перехвата)
сессии минусы- 15 минут жизни при неактивности пользователя.
плюсы - загрузка на сервере
- невозможность подделки пользователем

Comment: если я не ошибаюсь, стандартно время жизни сессии при неактивности - 10 мин, но это время можно задавать.

Comment: А где задавать? И когда очищаешь сессию это только для одного пользователя или для всех, и по чем оно различает пользователя: По ипу, по куки?

Comment: не знаю как на php проекте, но на java задаётся в web.xml. т.к. сессия создается для каждого отдельного пользователя, который подключился к серверу, то , соответственно, и очищается она для отдельного пользователя.

Comment: <a href="http://www.google.ru/search?q=php+время+жизни+сессии">гугл</a>

Answer (score 0):

Я бы вам советовал совместить куки и сессии, т.е. у пользователя могут быть выключены быть куки. И тогда хранить на сервере(сессия) данные.

Answer (score 0):

Я за сессии, т.к. пользователь может отключить куки. Это первое. Второе - сессии безопаснее, т.к. через определенный промежуток времени (по-дефолту 15 минут) сессии уничтожаются. Т.е., не так страшно, если пользователь забудет на чужом компе выйти из своего аккаунта.

Вывод: если проект действительно серьезный - сессии, если красть особо нечего  можно обойтись и куками.

Comment: А разве сессии без куков работают? :)
Гы, как интересно. А почему же тогда если удалить куку с sid, сессия сбрасывается?

Comment: без куков работают тоже, просто в конец адреса добавка садится. тот самый sid